# Determining if a field is a calculated field in MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, ms-access-2013, oledbconnection

I have an Access 2013 database and I'm trying to connect to it in C# and get information about the fields in the database. Everything is working except one thing I'm not sure about is how to determine if a field is a calculated field or not. Here is my Access database schema:

```
.---------------------------------------------------.
| TestTable1                                        |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| Field Name      | Data Type | Comments            |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| ID              | AutoNumber| Primary Key         |
| Field1ShortText | Short Text|                     |
| Field2LongText  | Long Text |                     |
| Field3Calculated| Calculated| Formula = 1+2       |
.---------------------------------------------------.
```

Here is my C# code:

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (DataTable columns = connect.GetSchema("Columns"))
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in columns.Rows)
        {
            if (((string)row["TABLE_NAME"]).ToLower() != tableName.ToLower())
                continue;

            var field = new Field();
            field.FieldName = (string) row["COLUMN_NAME"];
            field.IsCalculated = ? // Here is where I'm stuck
        }
    }
}
```

I'm iterating through all the columns in my Access database and I am setting a property called `IsCalculated`. This is a `bool` property that should be either `true` if its calculated or `false`. I'm not sure how to determine this. There is a column returned from `GetSchema` called `COLUMN_FLAGS`, which probably has the information I need. However, I cannot seem to find any reference documentation on what these "flags" are.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the answer here (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c8d7b3a6-cd99-4a45-a90b-66bfd6142b35/get-column-name-and-data-types-of-access-tables?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) help at all? I am not an access dev, but this was something I stumbled across.  My thought is, if the field type is "calculated" then you could set your bool based on that.  However, I don't know enough to post as an answer.

Comment: @Tommy - The problem is, the DATA_TYPE returned by `GetSchema` isn't returning `Calculated`. It's returning `Integer`, which my calculated answer is an integer, so that makes sense. However, it isn't helping me figure out if its truly calculated or just an ordinary integer field.

Comment: Fair enough - I wondered if it would but as I said, I couldn't quickly test and say yes or no since Access is not really "my jam".  Interesting question btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that if you want a definitive indication of a calculated field you will need to use Access DAO and inspect the `Expression` property of the `Field2` object in the `TableDef` for the table in question. For example:

```
// This code requires the following COM reference in your project:
//
//     Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
//
// and the declaration
//
//     using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;
//
// at the top of the class file            

var dbe = new DBEngine();
Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb");
foreach (Field2 fld in db.TableDefs["TestTable1"].Fields)
{
    if (fld.Expression.Length > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Field [{0}] is calculated.", fld.Name);
    }
}
db.Close();
```

Or, as suggested by another answer, you could create an `OleDbDataReader` object and look at the `DataTable` returned by the [OleDbDataReader.GetSchemaTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getschematable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#) method. The OleDb version does not include an `IsExpression` column but you might be able to infer the "calculated" status by looking for columns where `IsReadOnly` is `true`.

Comment: There is no IsReadOnly property in any of the properties of OleDb, so I had to include access interop "just" to get this info. Anyway, we can't do much just to adapt to what we have.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `GetSchemaTable()` method. The property you should be looking for is `IsExpression`. See the [MSDN for SqlDataReader.GetschemaTable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, but `OleDbDataReader#GetSchemaTable()` does not have an `IsExpression` column, so your answer applies to MS SQL Server but not MS Access.